# Is it possible to have an application recognize sound waves/frequienceis, then perform a task based on what it hears?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, voice

Ideally this will be in C#, as a part of a smart AI project that will be trained to the users exact voice

Comment: Yes, I believe it is!

Answer (score 0):

There are two main methods of voice recognition:

1) Given a small dictionary of words/phrases, determine if what was said is in the dictionary. Training to a speaker's voice is not necessary, but does help.

2) Train the software to a speaker's voice, then use that training to perform transcription.

I'm assuming you want 1). What I'm going to recommend is the Kinect. This has a C# library to handle 1) already, and is a rather high-quality microphone. (You might need the Windows version of Kinect; I haven't dealt with this for a few years now. It might depend if you're doing a school project or a commercial one.) This will allow you to convert the incoming voice to a text phrase, which you can do whatever you want with.